# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception

In my model I have this particular property to add two different model values and show it in my index page.

```
 public decimal Amount
    {
        get { return Products.Price * Qty; }

    }
```

When I go to my create page and try to create another sale after I hit submit I get a yellow screen of death with the following:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It points to this part of my model  get { return Products.Price * Qty; }

I'm not really interested in storing anything from here, and I don't even use the Amount property in my create page. Is there a way to tell it to ignore on submit?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: He's not asking what a null reference exception is. He's asking how to get around it in this scenario.

Comment: The one question pretty much answers the other.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
public decimal Amount
{        
    get
    {
        if (Products == null) { return 0; }
        return Products.Price * Qty;
    }
}
```

Comment: you'll want that `if` statement *inside* the `get` block